# Visual Basic - Array of strings with each index having it's own description

Tags: vb.net

I know the title is a little weird but this is what I would like to do. For example, there's an array of strings "Apple, Pear, Banna" and then have each one of them have a string dedicated to them for example Apple - **Red**, Pear - **Green**, Banna - **Yellow**. So I use a random to get a random index from the array and put that in a textbox and after that have another textbox show the dedicated string that's attached to that index in the array. I have an idea of just doing a Case statement but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this if I were, for example, having more than 1 string dedicated to one of the indexes in the array. This is what I have so far when it comes to code. It's not much but I would help it would get my idea across. Thanks to everyone who told me about the dictionary class.

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
        {{"1, room", "Can't kill zombies outside of spawn area."},
        {"Powerless Lifetime", "Can't turn on power"},
        {"Hot Potato", "Use a new gun every round"}}

    Dim ran As New Random

    Public Function challengeName()
        Dim result = dic.Values.ToList()(ran.Next(dic.Count))
        Return result
    End Function
```

So this gives me the value. Now what I would like is to get the Key associated with the value. Now I may be asking such a simple question here but I'm still trying to get the grasp of programming and with my skill of researching being terrible I sometimes have a little trouble with the simple things.

Comment: It seems that you are describing the functionality of the [Dictionary class](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet)

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135488/how-to-use-dictionary-in-vb-net

Comment: The paragraph is a little weird, too.  Not sure what help you are asking.

Comment: As suggested, a `Dictionary` is what you ought to use. If you were going to use an array though, you would just use concurrent arrays, i.e. two or more arrays of the same size where the elements at the same index were implicitly related. If you then generated a random index, you'd just use that to index both arrays.

Comment: I have updated my post with a little code to help explain what exactly I am trying to achieve. Hope it helps.

Comment: `Public Function ChallengeName() as String Return dic.Values(ran.Next(dic.Count)) End Function`. Keep in mind that the Dictionary is not an ordered collection. You should probably use a `List(Of Class)` or a simple `List(Of Tuple)` if you want to access the elements in the collection by index.

Comment: You could also return the KeyValuePair as `Dim kvp = dic.ElementAt(ran.Next(dic.Count))`, which is a shortcut to `Dictionary.AsEnumerable().ElementAt()`, but remember what mentioned above.

Comment: would you think the best way to go about this is 2 sets of arrays and just store the index of 1 to get the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two entries are linked by an index, you can put them into the same array. Just make an array of tuples:

```
Dim fruits As (fruit As String, dedicated As String)() =
    {
        ("Apple", "Red"),
        ("Pear", "Green"),
        ("Banana", "Yellow")
    }
```

Then you can loop through the entries like this:

```
For i = 0 To fruits.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine($"{fruits(i).fruit} - {fruits(i).dedicated}")
Next
```

This prints:

```
Apple - Red
Pear - Green
Banna - Yellow
```

See:

- [Tuples (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples)
- [Collection Initializers (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/)
- [Interpolated Strings (Visual Basic Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings)

---

However, if you first must search the array for an input to get the index, then a dictionary is better, since it yields the associated value directly:

```
Dim fruitColors As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
{
    {"Apple", "Red"},
    {"Pear", "Green"},
    {"Banna", "Yellow"}
}

Dim input As String = "Pear" ' Simulates a user input.
Dim color As String = ""
If fruitColors.TryGetValue(input, color) Then
    Console.WriteLine($"The color of {input} is {color}")
Else
    Console.WriteLine($"No fruit named {input} found.")
End If
```

If you know that the input exists, then you can skip the test with `TryGetValue` and instead use the default property:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The color of {input} is {fruitColors(input)}")
```

The expression `fruitColors(input)` yields the color related to a given input.

See:

- [VB.NET Dictionary Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet) (Dot Net Perls)

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes thank you for the very useful information. I have updated my post with some code so everyone could at least see what exactly I am trying to achieve with my oddly worded question.